# Spark Dataframes: Will a single row be entirely on a single cluster?

Tags: apache-spark

I haven't been able to find a good answer to that.

My understanding is that, in general, Spark is column-major in memory, so a scan each column will be faster than scanning across each row. But, is it really the case that it will put different fields of the same row on different machines, so that operations accessing multiple rows will require a shuffle?

My hope is that on each machine it would be column-major, but divided by rows between machines. I haven't found a real answer to this, though, and it's an important consideration if I'm going to have an instinct for the performance of my code.

Answer (score 0):

After project Tungsten, Spark stores row as internal data structure off-heap. One example of such a row is the following:

[image]

A set of such rows can be in one partition and be on a single node at a time.

For more details of Spark's memory management see the [link](https://databricks.com/session/deep-dive-apache-spark-memory-management).